# Julia: spawnat always runs on the same threads even if asked to run for multipleprocesses

Tags: multithreading, julia

I am trying to run the same simulation on different threads in Julia. My computer has 4 cores.
I checked that `Threads.nthreads() =4`, and added processes so that `nprocs() = 4`.
Now I am trying to run the same simulation:`simulation()` in parallel.

My code is

```
@spawnat 1 simulation() 
@spawnat 2 simulation()
@spawnat 3 simulation()
@spawnat 4 simulation()
```

the `simulation` function displays as well on which threads it runs thanks to a `println(Threads.threadid())`

The problem is that all processes run on the same thread - thread number 1.

I thought that creating workers and using the `@spawnat` macro should be enough for the simulation to run on all threads.

Would you have any idea on what to do, and what I did wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be confusing multi-threading and multi-processing? From the docs:

```
help?> @spawnat
  @spawnat p expr

  Create a closure around an expression and run the closure asynchronously on process p
```

So your code is executed on one of theworker processes you created with `addprocs`. Whether or not the code that is being executed uses more than one thread though depends on whether the code itself is multithreaded, so e.g. is using the `@threads` macro.

The Julia manual discusses multi-threading [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/multi-threading/#The-@threads-Macro) and multi-processing [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/distributed-computing/).

EDIT to add: there's a discussion on the Julia Discourse [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/multi-threaded-worker-processes/33034/) which includes an example of running multi-threaded worker processes - to do so you need to set an environment variable to ensure worker processes are started with multiple threads.

Comment: I don't know parallel code, and I can't really tell what a thread or process is just from the docs' intros, and they sound really similar. Learning by Google is also confusing because the terms have different meanings in other contexts and languages. I think the docs would benefit from adding ELI5 explanations, like how Tasks were explained as scheduled no-argument functions that can pause to give a turn to the next Task in the schedule queue.

Comment: @BatWannaBe I think the docs already do a good job here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/parallel-computing/. OTOH, threads and processes are really a fundamental building block independent of the language, similar to ints vs. floats. I don't think it is the job of the docs to explain OS and architecture concepts in detail.

Comment: That page's mention of sharing/not sharing memory helps a lot, thanks.